# Need suggestion in mysql for grouping the time difference between start time and end time

Tags: mysql

This is the query for calculating the **hour_diff** which i added in input

```
SELECT t.START_TIME, t.END_TIME, (TIME_TO_SEC(t.END_TIME) - TIME_TO_SEC(t.START_TIME))/(60*60) as hour_diff FROM table1 as t ;
```

**INPUT**

```
start time  --- end time ---- hour_diff
10:20:00        10:40:00      .33 hour
11:00:00        11:15:00      .25 hour
11:00:00        12:20:00      .33 hours
11:00:00        13:00:00       2  hours
14:00:00        17:00:00       3  hours
14:20:00        18:00:00       3.66 hours
```

**OUTPUT**
 I what that output should be categorized as

```
0th hour - 1st hour --> x1 rows
1st hour - 2nd hour ---> x2 rows
```

like this:

```
    0-1 ----> 3
    1-2 ----> 1
    2-3 ----> 1
    3-4 ----> 1
    4-5 ----> 0
```

Can someone suggest this I have start time and end time in my table, hours i now how to calculate that's why i included it in query but i don't know how to categorize it in hour basis.

Comment: Could you update your question with the query you used?

Comment: I added the query which i used for calculating hour_diff but i need after that how should we categorize the output row count on hourly basis

Comment: This isn't "input". See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try grouping by hour_diff like this and counting the number of results:

```
SELECT truncate((TIME_TO_SEC(t.END_TIME) - TIME_TO_SEC(t.START_TIME))/(60*60),0) as hour_diff, count(*)
FROM table1 as t 
group by truncate((TIME_TO_SEC(t.END_TIME) - TIME_TO_SEC(t.START_TIME))/(60*60),0);
```

Comment: can we also extend this for hour range [0-2], [2-4],.. like this?